# Trying to delete a line like below with notepad++

Tags: json, regex, replace, find, notepad++

I have a huge .json file that has a million lines in it, and would like to delete a line like below from my file. How should I go in doing that? I had tried using the following but only removes hours when it is in this format: "hours": {}
How should I modify my regex to delete everything on this line? Thanks!

My Regex:`"hours": \{.*?\}`

The code block that I would like to remove in JSON:

```
"hours": {"Monday": {"close": "19:00", "open": "10:00"}, "Tuesday": {"close": "19:00", "open": "10:00"}, "Friday": {"close": "19:00", "open": "10:00"}, "Wednesday": {"close": "19:00", "open": "10:00"}, "Thursday": {"close": "19:00", "open": "10:00"}, "Sunday": {"close": "18:00", "open": "11:00"}, "Saturday": {"close": "19:00", "open": "10:00"}}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your biggest problem would be the nested brackets, this would be easier to remove programatically... with js for example, something like: `delete jsonObj.hours`

Comment: Can you give more details what the lines you are going to remove have in common? E.g. can we remove all lines that start with `"hours":`?

Comment: @LarsFischer Yes I would like to remove all the lines that start with "hours":

Comment: @smerny I would like to remove the line within notepad++ using regex :)

Comment: Is hours always in its own single line?

Comment: @smerny its not in its own line, but within another set of {}. eg)  {"storeid: "Hsdf34", "hours": {"Monday": {"close": "19:00", "open": "10:00"}, "Tuesday": {"close": "19:00", "open": "10:00"}, "Friday": {"close": "19:00", "open": "10:00"}, "Wednesday": {"close": "19:00", "open": "10:00"}, "Thursday": {"close": "19:00", "open": "10:00"}, "Sunday": {"close": "18:00", "open": "11:00"}, "Saturday": {"close": "19:00", "open": "10:00"}}, "address": "1234 Sunset Avenue"}

Comment: Use [`"hours":\s*(\{(?>[^{}]++|(?1))*\})`](https://regex101.com/r/cG0kC8/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subroutine call inside the pattern to recurse the `{...}` subpattern:

```
"hours":\s*(\{(?>[^{}]++|(?1))*\})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cG0kC8/2)

Pattern explanation:

- `"hours":` - literal sequence `"hours":
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace
- `(\{(?>[^{}]++|(?1))*\})` - Group 1 that will be recursed with `(?1)` subroutine call (thus, will ensure recursion). This will match `{`, then 1 or more characters other than `{` and `}` or the whole Group 1 subexpression (with `(?1)`) and then the closing `}`.

[image]